# NSMutableDictionary iOS objective c appending

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I am having too Mutable Dictionary I want to append these two.
let a={name:zzz;price:rrr,quantity:www}
let b={name:vvv;price:lll;wuantity:qqq}

I want the appended dictionary as ab={{name:zzz;price:rrr;quantity:www};
{name:vvv;price:lll;quantity:qqq}}

I have saved one in nsuserdefaults so when I visit again I want to append the old selected item I want this for cart functionality

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"nsdef---  %@",[defaults objectForKey:@"tableview"]);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
self.rcolview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

NSMutableDictionary *tvar=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *tvarns=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[tvar setValue:self.lname forKey:@"name"];
[tvar setValue:self.price forKey:@"price"];
[tvar setValue:self.quan forKey:@"quantity"];
NSLog(@"tvar name--%@",[tvar valueForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"tvar quan--%@",[tvar valueForKey:@"quantity"]);
NSLog(@"tvar price--%@",[tvar valueForKey:@"price"]);

if(tvarns!=nil)
{
    //self.tvar=[defaults objectForKey:@"cid"];
    [tvar addEntriesFromDictionary:[defaults objectForKey:@"tableview"]];
    NSLog(@"tvar---%@",tvar);
    NSLog(@"tvarns---%@",tvarns);
}
else if (tvarns==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"tvarns is nil");
}
```

above is my code in view did load method

and this is my collection view

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {


ReviewViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later
    [cell.itemlbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.lname]];
    [cell.qtylbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.quan]];
    [cell.pricelbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.price]];
    NSMutableDictionary *tvarns=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [tvarns setValue:self.lname forKey:@"name"];
    [tvarns setValue:self.quan forKey:@"quantity"];
    [tvarns setValue:self.price forKey:@"price"];
    NSLog(@"%@",tvarns);


   // NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  //  [userDefaults setValue:self.tvarns forKey:@"tableview"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tvarns forKey:@"tableview"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

   // [userDefaults setObject:qtyns forKey:@"qtyns"];
   // [userDefaults setObject:priens forKey:@"priens"];
 //   [userDefaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tableview"]);


    return cell;
```

}

my aim is to hold the data until the customer shops for another product

and this is my log

```
2017-06-24 10:02:11.821 Barebones[740:18109] nsdef---  {
name = "Chicken Corn Chowder Soup";
price = 398;
quantity = 2;
}
2017-06-24 10:02:11.836 Barebones[740:18109] tvar name--Stella
2017-06-24 10:02:11.836 Barebones[740:18109] tvar quan--2
2017-06-24 10:02:11.837 Barebones[740:18109] tvar price--766
2017-06-24 10:02:11.837 Barebones[740:18109] tvar---{
name = "Chicken Corn Chowder Soup";
price = 398;
quantity = 2;
}
2017-06-24 10:02:11.838 Barebones[740:18109] tvarns---{
}
```

taverns ---nsuserdefaults dictionary
tvar---tableview dictionary I want the values to be appended to this dictionary

Comment: That mean you want to create array of dictionary

Comment: but how do u save a nsuserdefaults value and append to it??

Comment: if u have some example code share it!!thankyou!!

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want because you are saving data in UserDefaults inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` that is weird.

Comment: when will save data to userDefault ? while click on cell or while data populate to tableview.

Comment: when I get the first order I.e the item I m saving in user defaults so when customer comes to cart I get the next item append wth first item and then change the nsvalue to current item this was my logic

Comment: 1. Learn proper english. 2. Learn programming. 3. Profits